# How to print multidimensional arrays in php

Tags: php

I have an array in below format

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [product_id] => 33 [amount] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [product_id] => 34 [amount] => 3 ) [2] => Array ( [product_id] => 10 [amount] => 1 ) )
```

I want to get output from that array as below format

```
Product ID    Amount
33             1
34             3
10             1
```

Can anyone please help me regarding this problem. var_dump of the variable is.

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'product_id' => string '33' (length=2)
      'amount' => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array
      'product_id' => string '34' (length=2)
      'amount' => string '3' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array
      'product_id' => string '10' (length=2)
      'amount' => string '1' (length=1)
```

Comment: basic [foreach()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop

Comment: There are two thousand answers here http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+multidimensional, I'm sure one of them will help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe this is your array

```
$array = Array ( 
        0 => Array ( "product_id" => 33 , "amount" => 1 ) ,
        1 => Array ( "product_id" => 34  , "amount" => 3 ) ,
        2 => Array ( "product_id" => 10  , "amount" => 1 ) );
```

Using `foreach`

```
echo "<pre>";
echo "Product ID\tAmount";
foreach ( $array as $var ) {
    echo "\n", $var['product_id'], "\t\t", $var['amount'];
}
```

Using `array_map`

```
echo "<pre>" ;
echo "Product ID\tAmount";
array_map(function ($var) {
    echo "\n", $var['product_id'], "\t\t", $var['amount'];
}, $array);
```

Output

```
Product ID  Amount
33          1
34          3
10          1
```

Answer (score 3):

```
     <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Product Id</th>
            <th>Ammount</th>
        </tr>

        <?php
        foreach ($yourArray as $subAray)
        {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $subAray['product_id']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $subAray['amount']; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

```
foreach($arr as $a)
{
    echo $a['product_id'];
    echo $a['amount'];
}
```

Format as per your requirment.