# How can i print Multidimensional Arrays in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
Array       
(       
    [0] => Array        
        (       
            [0] => HUBZone Small Business       
            [1] => Small Disadvantaged Business     
            [2] => Service-Disabled Veteran Small Businesses        
        )       
)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12651864/how-to-print-multidimensional-arrays-in-php

Comment: use `print_r($array);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array ;

foreach($array as $key => $value){
   foreach($value as $k => $val){
      echo $val . "<br> ;
   }
}
```

Output:

```
HUBZone Small Business  
Small Disadvantaged Business
Service-Disabled Veteran Small Businesses
```

Comment: y not simpley use the print_r() function. in this way u cdont know how many foreach loops u have to use..

Answer (score 1):

```
print_r($array);
```

If given a string, integer or float, the value itself will be printed. If given an array, values will be presented in a format that shows keys and elements. Similar notation is used for objects.

For more info: [php.net/print_r](http://php.net/print_r)

Answer (score 0):

use `foreach`  loops.

For your above array:

```
   foreach($arr as $a){
       foreach($a as $k=>$v){
           echo $v;
       }
    }
```

Comment: y not simpley use the `print_r()` function. in this way u cdont know how many foreach loops u have to use..