# PHP display results of multidimensional array in foreach

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

This should be a failry simple question for a more experienced programmer.

Im working on a basic "pickem app" which allows users to predict who lets users vote on who they believe will win a sports game. Simple enough.

I wrote the following function to display statistics for each match. I.E the function returns how many votes each team received.

Doing a `print_r()` on the function it works perfectly and returns the correct results. The results are returned in the form of a multidimensional array containing. `gameID`, `team`, `number_of_votes`

**My Code**

```
$sql='SELECT gameID, team, COUNT(*) AS number_of_picks
          FROM picks
          WHERE picks.tournament = :tournament AND picks.weekNum = :weekNum 
          GROUP BY gameID, team
          ORDER BY gameID, team';
    $stmnt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmnt->bindValue(':tournament', $tournament);
    $stmnt->bindValue(':weekNum', $week);
    $stmnt->execute();
    if ($stmnt->rowCount() > 0) {
        $result = array();
        foreach ($stmnt->fetchAll() as $row) {
            $result[$row['gameID']][] = $row;
        }
        return $result;
        }
    return false;
}
```

**Print_R function return data**

[image: ![enter image description here]

**My Problem**

My problem is displaying / echo'ing the data in my foreach loop. [I have searched on SO and most answers points towards a simple `foreach()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12651864/how-to-print-multidimensional-arrays-in-php)

```
$picks = $calcStats('Tournament', Round);
foreach($picks as $pick){
echo $pick['gameID']; //gameID
echo $pick['team']; //Which Team Will Win
echo $pick['number_of_votes'] //How many votes did each team get
}
```

My problem is I keep on getting NULL values back when trying to echo variables above. I made a number of tweaks to the loop with same result.

What am I missing here? Any help / advice appreciated...

Comment: *"Doing a print_r() on the function it works perfectly"* - So where is that implemented in your test? You're also `return`'ing results, where and how are you using that return? return stops execution there and I don't know if you're using a class/methods to retrieve/echo those.

Comment: According to your print_r, you don't have `gameID` or `number_of_votes`.

Comment: there goes the screenshot

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner wrong screenshot appologies

Comment: @JonStirling I uploaded wrong screenshot appologies

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner please see update

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee So it's a multi-dimensional array? So you'll need 2 foreach..es

Comment: According to your screenshot there is array inside  array so you need 2 for loops

Comment: @JonStirling so you are saying I will need a foreach() inside a foreach() I can get the logic behind that but it seems a bit inefficient.... Do you know if PHP perhaps has a build in function for a scenario as per question (sorting / getting data from mulidimensional arrays...?)

Comment: You _might_ be able to use `array_walk_recursive`, but if you're needing data from all the sub-arrays, then I'm not sure how you could be more efficient that going through every one.

Comment: @JonStirling Thank you! I do indeed need the sub-array values. I got them with the following `foreach ($picks as $pick) {
            foreach ($pick as $key => $votes) {
                echo $key . ' = ' . $votes['team'] . '='. $votes['number_of_picks']. '<br />';
            }
        }` Im keeping question open though to see if someone can come up with something "better / more efficient"

Comment: you need one more nested foreach()

Comment: 5 years as a member. 2000+ rep points. 60+ badges. And still we get screenshots of text. Why? That alone is worth at least five downvotes.

Comment: number_of_picks <> number_of_votes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `print_r()` array is $picks, then your array is a multidimensional array, you need one more nested foreach() like below:

```
<?php
    $picks = $calcStats('Tournament', Round);
    foreach($picks as $keyArr){
        foreach($keyArr as $pick)
            echo $pick['gameID']; //gameID
            echo $pick['team']; //Which Team Will Win
            echo $pick['number_of_picks'] //it should be this according to your print_r data
        }
    }
```