# Calculating number of occurrences in array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Consider the following `print_r()` of an array

[image]

**Problem**

There are 4 users who make predictions on the result of 3 matches in a tournament Calculate how many votes each team got.

**PSEUDO**

- Each match should have a total of 4 votes (since 4 users are voting)
- There are 3 outcomes HomeTeam Picked to win, AwayTeam Picked to win, Draw Picked
- Loop over array keep track of number of votes in each match for Home Team, Away Team, Draw.

  **My Code to solve above problem**

  ```
  foreach($results as $result){
      $homeTeam = $result['homeTeam'];
      $awayTeam = $result['awayTeam'];
      $draw = 'Draw';
      $pickedTeam = $result['pickedTeam'];
      $nrVotes = $result['nrVotes'];
      $gameID = $result['gameID'];
      //CHECK IF NEW MATCH OR SAME MATCH ON ITERATION
      if($gameID !== $newGameID) {

          if ($homeTeam === $pickedTeam) {
              $homeVotes = $nrVotes;
              //homeTeam Got 0 Votes
              if (!isset($homeVotes)) {
                  $homeVotes = 0;
              }
          }
          if ($awayTeam === $pickedTeam) {
              $awayVotes = $nrVotes;
              //AWAY Team Got 0 Votes
              if (!isset($awayVotes)) {
                  $awayVotes = 0;
              }
          }
          if ($pickedTeam === $draw) {
              $drawVotes = $nrVotes;
              //Draw Got Zero Votes
              if (!isset($drawVotes)) {
                  $drawVotes = 0;
              }
          }

          echo $homeTeam . 'Number Of Votes = ' . $homeVotes;
          echo '<br />';
                 echo $awayTeam . 'Number Of Votes = ' . $awayVotes;
          echo '<br />';
          echo $draw . ' Number Of Votes = ' . $drawVotes;
      }
      //CHECK FOR NEW MATCH
      $newGameID = $result['gameID'];
     }//foreach
  ```

If been staring at the PC screen for a long time so Im not sure if it is a small logical error or if my approach is completely wrong, as im getting a weird output as can be seen on below screen shot:

**Code Output**
[image]

Notice how the number of draw votes seem to get correctly calculated but not the rest....*that is where my problem is, ive been stuck on if for hours*

**Additional Info DB table**

[image]

Any help much appreciated.

**UPDATE MYSQL QUERY**

```
$sql ='SELECT picks.*, schedule.homeTeam, schedule.awayTeam, schedule.gameID, picks.team, COUNT(*) AS number_of_picks
FROM picks
JOIN schedule ON picks.gameID = schedule.gameID
WHERE picks.tournament = :tournament AND picks.weekNum = :weekNum
GROUP BY schedule.gameID, picks.team
ORDER BY schedule.gameID, picks.team';
```

Comment: Again a picture of an array output. Stop posting text as pictures!

Comment: Out of curiosity - is this homework?

Comment: Your problem is this: `if($gameID !== $newGameID)`, your code is only going to run for the first entry for each game in your array.

Comment: @andres so what is best practice...copy pasting the output? I simply feel its helpful to know the content of the array if I shouldn't post it as a picture I do apologize and did not know.

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee `var_export()` is the best way since it can be copy/pasted

Comment: is it possible to do it as sql query: select gameID having sum(number_of_picks) >= 4?

Comment: Thank you @billyonecan I'll note that for next time (nice username bydaway)

Comment: @simon small web app I need to develop for a uni project, why are you asking out of curiosity?

Comment: @billyonecan yeah however If I do implement your suggestion I get more outputs than matches...Id like to show you, but not sure what todo...is it considered acceptable to post output as image

Comment: Is $newGameId declared before the loop? Also because each result is being read the statements should be printed for each result, hence why you have some empty values. Ie Read a result relating to a Draw also prints out the values for Votes for both the Home and Away Team which might not exist.

Easy way to fix this is to modify the database and add columns to track num_of_picks_home, num_of_picks_away, num_of_picks_draw. Than you only have one record which records all the info you require.

Comment: I told you just a few hours ago, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48642724/php-display-results-of-multidimensional-array-in-foreach#comment84283646_48642724 . With text it's easier to read. It's possible to copy paste. And by the looks of it, you have saved as a jpg file. Jpg is not suitable for computer graphics. It creates blurry images.

Comment: @mcv thank you for your comment. NO `$newGameId` is NOT declared before the loop. It will be undefined on the first iteration and updated on each iteration there after. See update on question for mysql query

Comment: @Andreas I honestly didnt see that comment and did not know -- this is literally the first time Ive had someone complain about a screenshot. But thank you I'll keep it in mind for the future (P.S friendliness cost nothing smile pal) You think im purposelessly gonna post something that is viewed as bad practice. I take a great amount of time / effort to format any question I ask as good as I can, I just never knew about images...so once again humble apologies.

Comment: Ok got it. Sorry for the "bad comment".

Comment: yeah that if statement is going to definitely block some of your outputs. refer to the post by @simon below. it collects all the info you need. you just need to loop through the result set to create your statements. use var_dump($arr) to see contents of your array afterwards

Answer (score 3):

You have some issues in your code. First of all, the logical mistake you made lies here:

```
if($gameID !== $newGameID)
```

The `if` block will only be executed when the game ID changes, which of course only happens for the first entry for every game ID. That's why only the draw votes are correct.

Then there are some variables that you have never declared (e.g. `$newGameID`). This will yield a notice and is bad (even if you don't see it because `display_errors` is probably set to 0).

Furthermore, all your `isset()`s like here:

```
$homeVotes = $nrVotes;
if (!isset($homeVotes)) {
```

are pretty useless as you're declaring the variable right before, so `!isset()` will always evaluate to false.

I'd personally go for an array in this situation and do something like this:

```
$arr = array();
$currentGameId = -1;
foreach($results as $result) {
    $gameId = $result['gameID'];
    $homeTeam = $result['homeTeam'];
    $awayTeam = $result['awayTeam'];
    $pickedTeam = $result['pickedTeam'];
    $nrVotes = $result['nrVotes'];

    // initialize new subarray if game id changes
    if ($gameId != $currentGameId) {
        $arr[$gameId]['homeVotes'] = 0;
        $arr[$gameId]['awayVotes'] = 0;
        $arr[$gameId]['drawVotes'] = 0;

        // remember current game id
        $currentGameId = $gameId;
    }

    // add votes
    if ($pickedTeam == $homeTeam) {
        $arr[$gameId]['homeVotes'] += $nrVotes;
    } elseif ($pickedTeam == $awayTeam) {
        $arr[$gameId]['awayVotes'] += $nrVotes;        
    } else {
        $arr[$gameId]['drawVotes'] += $nrVotes;
    }
}
```

This will give you an array with the game IDs as index like this:

```
Array
(
    [127] => Array
        (
            [homeVotes] => 2
            [awayVotes] => 0
            [drawVotes] => 2
        )

    [128] => Array
        (
            [homeVotes] => 2
            [awayVotes] => 1
            [drawVotes] => 1
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2):

As billyonecan mentionned, your problem is

```
if($gameID !== $newGameID)
```

If you look at your array data, you'll notice that $results[0] is the first occurence of match 127 and it gives the amount of draw votes. Your if statement will make $results[1] and $results[2] be ignored.
The same thing happens with match 128 and so on.

The way around this is to declare your variables first, and every time you change game number, you echo your variables and then reset them (don't forget to use the information contained in this line or you'll be missing a value);

Your code would look something like this:

```
<?php
function output($homeTeam, $homeVotes, $awayTeam, $awayVotes, $draw, $drawVotes){
    echo $homeTeam . ' Number Of Votes = ' . $homeVotes;
    echo '<br />';
    echo $awayTeam . ' Number Of Votes = ' . $awayVotes;
    echo '<br />';
    echo $draw . ' Number Of Votes = ' . $drawVotes;
    echo '<br />';
}

$results = array(
    0 => array('gameID' => '127','homeTeam' => 'Wales','awayTeam' => 'Scotland','pickedTeam' => 'Draw','nrVotes' => '3'),
    1 => array('gameID' => '127','homeTeam' => 'Wales','awayTeam' => 'Scotland','pickedTeam' => 'Wales','nrVotes' => '1'),
    2 => array('gameID' => '128','homeTeam' => 'France','awayTeam' => 'Ireland','pickedTeam' => 'Draw','nrVotes' => '1'),
    3 => array('gameID' => '128','homeTeam' => 'France','awayTeam' => 'Ireland','pickedTeam' => 'France','nrVotes' => '2'),
    4 => array('gameID' => '128','homeTeam' => 'France','awayTeam' => 'Ireland','pickedTeam' => 'Ireland','nrVotes' => '1')
);

$homeVotes = 0;
$awayVotes = 0;
$drawVotes = 0;
$newGameID = $results[0]['gameID'];

foreach($results as $result){
    $homeTeam = $result['homeTeam'];
    $awayTeam = $result['awayTeam'];
    $draw = 'Draw';
    $pickedTeam = $result['pickedTeam'];
    $nrVotes = $result['nrVotes'];
    $gameID = $result['gameID'];

    //CHECK IF NEW MATCH OR SAME MATCH ON ITERATION
    if($gameID !== $newGameID) {
        // New match, output and reset
        output($homeTeam, $homeVotes, $awayTeam, $awayVotes, $draw, $drawVotes);
        $homeVotes = 0;
        $awayVotes = 0;
        $drawVotes = 0;

        if ($homeTeam === $pickedTeam) {
            $homeVotes = $nrVotes;
            //homeTeam Got 0 Vote
            if (!isset($homeVotes)) {
                $homeVotes = 0;
            }
        }
        if ($awayTeam === $pickedTeam) {
            $awayVotes = $nrVotes;
            //AWAY Team Got 0 Votes
            if (!isset($awayVotes)) {
                $awayVotes = 0;
            }
        }
        if ($pickedTeam === $draw) {
            $drawVotes = $nrVotes;
            //Draw Got Zero Votes
            if (!isset($drawVotes)) {
                $drawVotes = 0;
            }
        }

    }

    else {
        // The same match

        if ($homeTeam === $pickedTeam) {
            $homeVotes = $nrVotes;
            //homeTeam Got 0 Vote
            if (!isset($homeVotes)) {
                $homeVotes = 0;
            }
        }
        if ($awayTeam === $pickedTeam) {
            $awayVotes = $nrVotes;
            //AWAY Team Got 0 Votes
            if (!isset($awayVotes)) {
                $awayVotes = 0;
            }
        }
        if ($pickedTeam === $draw) {
            $drawVotes = $nrVotes;
            //Draw Got Zero Votes
            if (!isset($drawVotes)) {
                $drawVotes = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    //CHECK FOR NEW MATCH
    $newGameID = $result['gameID'];
   }//foreach

   //This line outputs the last match which would not be output otherwise.
   output($homeTeam, $homeVotes, $awayTeam, $awayVotes, $draw, $drawVotes);
?>
```

The if statements that are used to update the values should be put into a function in order to avoid replicate code.
Hope it helps